# Can't get webpack usedExport / treeshaking to work

Tags: webpack, webpack-5, tree-shaking

Been trying for hours to get webpack to treeshake my code. Here's the repro: https://github.com/dmt0/treeshake-repro

The problem is that even though I'm importing only a few icons from `@mdi/js`, the whole bundle of 2.6MB gets imported.

Reread the [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationusedexports) multiple times and saw multiple SO questions and GH issues. I do have the following in place:

- package.json has

```
   "sideEffects": [
    "*.scss",
    "*.css"
  ],
```

- Babel is configured with `"modules": false`
- webpack config has `usedExports: true`.
- Terser is configured to do 3 passes (see that sometimes one pass is not enough).
- `production` mode is enabled.
- `providedExports` and `usedExports` are enabled.
- `sideEffects` are set to `false` in the `package.json` of the [imported library](https://github.com/Templarian/MaterialDesign-JS/blob/0ecb7b73849a5fde91d66bb3c394e09259e4c10e/package.json#L8):

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in some completely unrelated setting - `devtool`. No idea why it breaks treeshaking. It was never changed in this config file since some ancient version of webpack. Had to change from this:

```js
  devtool: env.production ? 'hidden-source-map' : 'eval-source-map',
```

to this:

```js
  devtool: argv.mode === 'production' ? 'hidden-source-map' : 'eval-source-map',
```

Now treeshaking works correctly and my bundle size went down significantly.